# Expectation of random variable given an equation of a different random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\alpha$ be a uniform distribution random variable over $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, assuming $\alpha$ is the angle which is made with the positive $y$ axis.
Assuming a linear equation that pass through point $[0,-1]$ and has $\alpha$ as the angle, find the density function and the expectation of where the linear equation will hit x.

My attempt:

Since the point starts from $y=-1$ then we can conclude that the following equation holds for the $y=0$: $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{x}{1}=x$, it follows that $\alpha=\arctan(x)$

The density function of the a uniform distribution $\alpha$ is $f_\alpha(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\pi}$ when $\alpha \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] $ and $0$ everywhere else.

Putting the equations together gives a new density function $f_x(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}$ when $x\in R$, however this is not a density function, what did I do wrong?

I plotted alpha for different equations given different $\alpha$ because it might not be clear what angle I am talking about.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calculating the density function, the distribution function of $X$ is usually calculated, where $X$ is the position that the line hits the $x$-axis. For fixed $x$, we have
$$
\Pr(X \leq x) = \Pr\left(-\frac{\pi}{2} < \alpha \leq \arctan(x)\right) = \frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}
$$ 
Therefore, the density function of $X$ is just the derivative of $\Pr(X \leq x)$; that is,
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(x^2 + 1)}
$$

Comment: Oh I see, it makes sense, thank you.